# How to properly set up jfxtras iCalendarAgenda in intellij

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, jfxtras

I am trying to use the calendar plug in by jfxtras. I originally tried setting the project up as a maven project or gradle project and importing the jfxtras-all, and setting the snapshot to latest. Unfortunately it seems that iCalendarfx and iCalendarAgenda are not included in this. So I tried just downloading the zip on github. But after setting a file up that had them all in the jfxtras package it gave me a Java.lang.runtime exception. I think maybe it would be best to make a jar of these libraries but I don't really know. Any suggestions as to how to include these libraries would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Yeah. JFXtras-all is giving me headaches. Gradle, Asciidoc and maven central turn out to be a stubborn combination; Maven central requires a javadoc plus a source jar to be uploaded with the actual jar, but I'm not able to generate these jars with Gradle for jfxtras-all given the javadoc is written using asciidoc. So I'm seriously considering dropping gradle. So right now I would advise using the separate artifacts like jfxtras:controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. I included every library in maven separately. For some reason labs has to have a snapshot of 8.0-r4 instead of 8.0-r5. And then I downloaded the zip from github and just included the Java files of iCalendaragenda and iCalendar fx.